# how to save the particular cell value in database

Tags: infragistics

I have ultrawinGrid related to infragistics.
In my Grid I have the column name with "Area" when user enters the value in a cell row  after click on save button the value should save in database please provide the code whether I can implement in this event 
ex:private void syncGrid_CellChange(object sender, CellEventArgs e)
{
}

Answer (score 0):

The UltraGrid is bound to a list that is in memory and that list will automatically have the updates so there is no need to handle the CellChange event of the UltraGrid.  In the event handler for the button you will need to add logic that will persist the list the grid is bound to to the database.

If you are using a DataTable/DataSet, TableAdapters provide this functionality.  If you are using EntityFramework, call SaveChanges on your DBContext.